# How to allocate different IP while crawling web pages

Tags: proxy, ip, web-crawler

How can i assign different ip address while crawling

I am crawling billions of page everyday(allocating different ip will help to handle blockages)

Comment: you can try using different proxies for your requests.

Comment: @Ben Could you please give me an example?

Comment: It depends on how do you crawl the billions of websites. Maybe your website-crawler offers this option. You should provide some more infos about your crawler.

Comment: i use wget and curl to download webpage and use regular expressions to extract data from download web page(This is how i build web crawlers)

Comment: as example, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211705/setting-proxy-in-wget .Then you need to create a script or small tool which iterates over a list of proxies and set them for each wget.

Answer (score 2):

You have different options for having different IPs. Usually, what you have to do is use some proxy, I usually recommend choosing a good VPN which allows you to switch easily the connection between their servers, that way you can easily have different IPs once they get blocked.

So typically, you'll start crawling and once the IP gets blocked, you can switch to another server from the VPN and start crawling again.

Just make sure the VPN provider allows you to do that as some don't.

The other option is to use a proxy for crawlers. This is a service which offers you an endpoint which you can call and they will always give you a response. This way you don't have to worry about IPs, blockages, limits, etc...

So far I know two services [proxycrawl](https://proxycrawl.com) and [crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera/), I've used both and they are really good, proxycrawl is cheaper and faster than the other one. I suggest you try both and use the one which fits you better.